# Vue/Bluebird: then callback doesn't run

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bluebird

The then() for `this.getStationsAsync()` never runs. The `catch()` doesn't either, so there is likely nothing being rejected. Could I be doing something wrong with `Promise.promisify(this.getStations)`?

I have also tried `this.getStationsAsync = Promise.promisify(this.getStations)` inside the `created()` hook. I'm not getting any errors, but also not getting any `console.logs()` indicating that the `then()` executed.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import Promise from 'bluebird'

methods:{
createStationMarkers (selectedNetworkMarker) {
      this.selectedNetwork = selectedNetworkMarker
      this.hideNetworkMarkers()
      debugger
      this.getStationsAsync()
      .then(() => {
        debugger
        console.log('inside then')
        this.addStationMarkers()
        this.test = true
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    }
},
getStations () {
      axios
        .get('/api/network/' + this.selectedNetwork.id)
        .then(res => {
          for (let station of res.data.stations) {
            this.stations.push(station)
          }
          return res.data.stations
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }
}

computed: {
    getStationsAsync () {
      return Promise.promisify(this.getStations)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *return* the result of the axios call, which is a promise.

```
getStations () {
  return axios
    .get('/api/network/' + this.selectedNetwork.id)
    .then(res => {
      for (let station of res.data.stations) {
        this.stations.push(station)
      }
      return res.data.stations
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
}
```

Bluebird is uneeccessary. Simply call `getStations` from `createStationMarkers`.

Comment: and also I think using `Bluebird.promisify()` is redundant as `axios` also return a promise... moreover it is considered a anti-practice (not sure though)

Comment: @riyaz-ali I agree.